# How can i copy a df2 to df1 if the name of the worksheet in df1 matches with a string value

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I have two different data frames (df1&df2) and df1 has a few worksheets but the df2 has only one worksheet. Additionaly, I have a string which is 'checker = Airplane'. What I would like to do is to check if df1 has a worksheet named as 'Airplane'. If yes, I would like to copy df2 to the Airplane worksheet in the df1. I would be happy to hear some suggestions. Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
#pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)

excel_file1 = 'Excel_1.xlsx'
excel_file2 = 'Excel_2.xlsx'

df1 = pd.read_excel(excel_file1, None)
df2 = pd.read_excel(excel_file2, 'Tram')

checker = 'Airplane'

print(df1)
print(df2)
```

Comment: so you have 2 different excel files or 2 files please elaborate more

Comment: There are 2 different excel files @Hietsh Kumar

Comment: so you want to move data from one excel to another if sheet name matches..?

Comment: Exactly @Hietsh Kumar

Comment: Check my answer down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any number of sheet in file 1 or File 2 we don't have to consider that if we are writing the data on when its match , I am appending and writing into different file you can use same file same sheet as well. Let me know if it works. Data File snaps are after code lines

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel('File1.xlsx',sheet_name='Airplane')
# Read Lit of All the Sheets in the file 2
all_sheets = pd.ExcelFile('File2.xlsx')
worksheets = all_sheets.sheet_names

# Loop and compare checker
checker = 'Airplane'
for wsh in worksheets:
    print(wsh)
    if wsh==checker:
        df2 = pd.read_excel('File2.xlsx',sheet_name='Airplane')
        # Append Data from File 2 Airplane Sheet
        df1 = df1.append(df2)
        # After Appending the dataframe lets check the output
        print(df1.head(6))
        # you can write the output on excel to
        df1.to_excel('Output.xlsx',index=False)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I did some adjustments and the problem is totaly solved.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to check whether aeroplane named worksheet available in df1 so this below code is used

```
 import pandas as pd
 # importing openpyxl module 
 import openpyxl as xl; 

 #variables for source file, worksheets, and empty array for dataframes
 spreadsheet_file = pd.ExcelFile('df1.xlsx')
 # Fetch sheets names
 worksheets = spreadsheet_file.sheet_names
```

Now open destination and source file using openpyxl

```
 # opening the source excel file 
filename ="df2.xlsx"
wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename) 
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]

# opening the destination excel file 
filename1 ="df1.xlsx"
wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename1) 
ws2 = wb2.active
```

Calculate rows and columns from source file

```
# calculate total number of rows and  
# columns in source excel file 
mr = ws1.max_row 
mc = ws1.max_column
```

Now Check wether destination file having "Aeroplane" work sheet, if yes then paste rows from df2 file to areoplane source worksheet

```
checked = "Aeroplane"
if checked in worksheets:
ws2=wb2["Aeroplane"]
# copying the cell values from source  
# excel file to destination excel file 
for i in range (1, mr + 1): 
    for j in range (1, mc + 1): 
        # reading cell value from source excel file 
        c = ws1.cell(row = i, column = j) 
        # writing the read value to destination excel file 
        ws2.cell(row = i, column = j).value = c.value 
    # saving the destination excel file 
    wb2.save(str(filename1))
```

Comment: Thank you! It really helped me.

Comment: Glad to know that